# How to change mp4 aspect ratio to 16:9 using ffmpeg?

Tags: youtube, ffmpeg, aspect-ratio

I got an mp4 video that I copy 4 minute of it using ffmpeg. After uploading  to YouTube I noticed the uploaded video has black bars on both side of video(right and left side)!After searching for a way to remove those black bars I found that I need to use yt:stretch=16:9!However,using yt:stretch=16.9 tag will not remove the black bars on iPhone and Samsung smart tv YouTube app!

could an expert help me change the aspect ratio of original mp4 video to 16:9 using ffmpeg (without losing video quality) for re uploading to YouTube? Thanks in advance ?

I got two types of source with following information:

```
1)Resolution:720x576 ,Frame rate:25 . Codec:H264 - MPEG-4 AVC(part 10)(avc1),
2)Resolution:848x480 , Frame rate:24.804393,Codec:H264 - MPEG-4 AVC(part 10)(avc1)
```

ffmpeg code used to trim the original video:

```
   ffmpeg -i orginalVideo.mp4 -ss 00:25:55 -t 00:04:02 -acodec copy -vcodec copy videoForYoutube.mp4
```

Comment: If your video content is not 16:9, then changing aspect will distort it. What's the current resolution?

Comment: Thanks for reply I got two types of source with following information:
1)Resolution:720x576 ,Frame rate:25 . Codec:H264 - MPEG-4 AVC(part 10)(avc1),
2)Resolution:848x480 , Frame rate:24.804393,Codec:H264 - MPEG-4 AVC(part 10)(avc1) Using youtube tag to stretch the already uploaded video didn't distort the the video much on youtube player on firefox pc .

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately none of the provided answers seemed to do the trick for me with MKV file and FFMpeg 5.1.2.

[I found this](https://superuser.com/a/1430739/1773069) simple command after some diving that does the trick converting video to 16:9 aspect ratio:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c copy -aspect 16/9 output.mkv
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the video looks acceptable after stretching, you can use the following command:

```
ffmpeg -ss 25:55 -t 4:02 -i input.mp4 -vf scale=ih*16/9:ih,scale=iw:-2,setsar=1 -crf 20 -c:a copy YT.mp4
```

Comment: I get these errors on ffmpeg window:[libx264 @ 04e67020] width not divisible by 2 (853x480)
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
How to fix them ?

Comment: 'ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf scale=854x480,setdar=16/9 output.mp4' worked for me without any errors. Make sure the dimensions you are using are divisible by the scale. Eg 16:9. '854x480' vs '853x480'

Answer (score 1):

This command is also useful

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -crf=20 -vf 'split[original][copy];[copy]scale=ih*16/9:-1,crop=h=iw*9/16,gblur=sigma=80,eq=saturation=0.9[background];[background][original]overlay=(main_w-overlay_w)/2:(main_h-overlay_h)/2' output.mp4
```

this command unlike **Gyan** command expends the size of the video without stretching it and it takes more time to convert but **Gyan** command is faster.

[source](https://blog.natetodd.com/convert-vertical-video-to-16-9-with-ffmpeg/)

---

Has been tested using `ffmpeg version 3.4.8-0ubuntu0.2` on `linux`